# GridView repeating content on each call android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have an `Arraylist<HashMap<String,String>>` with three records . I am displaying them using a `CustomAdapter` which extends `BaseAdapter`.

In first call I am getting three records in gridview.

In second call I am getting 3+3 = 6 records.(same 3 again)

In third call I am getting 3+3+3 = 9 calls and so on.

I used `grid.invalidateViews()`. But it is not working please help.

Comment: add some code... My experience tells me there is some problem in the getView() method. anyway post your code.

Answer (score 0):

When You put your ArrayList in CustomAdepter then Your Arraylist not clear . 
So you  should use `arryList.clear();` in your class before putting new elements in it

Comment: actually my arraylist was static , I just removed the static keyword and it starts working fine.thankxx coz I noticed "static when I was going to apply your suggetion.